# Azure SQL upgrade/downgrades

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a few questions regarding upgrades/downgrades of azure sql. The only information I found was that to upgrade/downgrade you have to export a .bacpac and import it on a new upgraded/downgraded server.

1. Does Microsoft "force" you on to newer versions of azure sql when they are available?
2. How do you upgrade your current azure sql version?
3. How do you downgrade your current azure sql version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a SQL server version property on the Azure SQL **Server** créate request ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/servers/createorupdate#serverversion)). The DB created on that server will just inherit that versión.

As for your question:

1. Probably at some point in time it might, not that it happens often. This happened once (as far as I recall) and I dont remember if they forced you to migrate or not, probably did at some point.
2. Create new server, Backup\Restore databases
3. Create new server, Backup\Restore databases

I dont think points 2 and 3 have any real application in the current state of affairs, since Azure SQL is almost locked to v12 (which **isnt** equivalent to SQL 2012), I can hardly imagine a case where you would want to downgrade (and there's no room to upgrade).